# Video not centering when margin 0 auto applied to parent container

Tags: css, video, sass, centering

I'm trying to center a video horizontally.

```
<section class="root">
  <div class="bg-video">
    <video class="bg-video__content" autoplay muted loop>
      <source src="https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Video not supported.
    </video>
  </div>
</section>
```

```
*
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html
{
  font-size: 10px;
}

.bg-video__content
{
  display: block;
  max-width: 100rem;
  margin: 0 auto;         
}

.root
{
  // why won't this work?
  // display: block;
  // max-width: 100rem;
  // margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If I try to center .bg-video__content directly it works. But if I try to center .root it doesn't work as expected.

```
.root
{
  // why won't this work?
  display: block;
  max-width: 100rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I want to center the video by centering the container of video.

Here's a live demo: https://codepen.io/loganlee/pen/LYVPPww?editors=1100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.bg-video__content` element is your `<video>`, whereas `.root` is an ancestor. The CSS property [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) is not [inherited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance). Thus, when your `margin: 0 auto` is only applied to `.root`, the `<video>` element takes on the initial (unaligned) value:

> When no value for a non-inherited property has been specified on an element, the element gets the initial value of that property (as specified in the property's summary).